# How to increase the speed of table creation with index and constraints?

Tags: oracle

I have to create more than 500 tables having the same columns,indexes and constraints.

In The below code I have created table called TABLE_1 like wise i have to create tables from TABLE_1 to TABLE_500....

It takes more time for creating 500 tables and indexes.

Is there any way to increase speed of table creation.?

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (FEATURE_ID NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,  
                      COL_1 VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),  
                      COL_2 VARCHAR2(5 CHAR),  
                      COL_3 NUMBER(*,0),  
                      COL_4 NUMBER(*,0),  
                      COL_5 VARCHAR2(5 CHAR),  
                      COL_6 CHAR(5 BYTE),   
                      COL_7 NUMBER(*,0),  
                      COL_8 VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),  
                      COL_9 NUMBER(*,0),  
                      COL_10 VARCHAR2(20 CHAR),  
                      GEOMETRY SDO_GEOMETRY);                 

CREATE BITMAP INDEX TABLE_1_DM_IDX ON TABLE_1(COL_3);  

CREATE BITMAP INDEX TABLE_1_ATR_IDX ON TABLE_1(COL_4);  

CREATE INDEX TABLE_1_SPATIAL_IDX ON TABLE_1(GEOMETRY)  
INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;  

ALTER TABLE TABLE_1 ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE_1_PK PRIMARY KEY (FEATURE_ID);      


ALTER TABLE TABLE_1 ADD CONSTRAINT TABLE_1_PK PRIMARY KEY (FEATURE_ID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a PLSQL script that creates the names for you.

```
    begin
      for i in 1..500 loop
         execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE TABLE_'||i|| '
                            (FEATURE_ID NUMBER(*,0)  NOT NULL ENABLE,  
                             COL_1 VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),  
                             COL_2 VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), 
                             ... ';
         execute immediate 'CREATE BITMAP INDEX TABLE_'||i||'_DM_IDX ON TABLE_'||i||'(COL_3)';

         ... etc.

      end loop;
    end;
/
```